# How to get rid of extra Untitled Article in html5 document outline when using new WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, loop, html5

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm using on a static homepage template made for a child theme of TwentyTwelve. I simplified some of the divs used for styling and just focused on the problem area.

The problem is when I view this using the Chrome extension to see the html5 outline, everything looks fine except the Featured Comic section has 2 articles underneath it (should only show 1). One article for the sticky post it's supposed to pull in and one labeled 'Untitled Article' (which when clicked gives me the post ID of the next post after the sticky one but isn't showing any content) and then another entry for the h3 'Subheading'.

I would like to keep the multiple loops on the page so the user can update the static homepage content. Is there something I'm missing to get rid of this phantom Untitled Article?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div><!—-for styling only-—>

<section>
<h2>Featured Comic</h2>
<?php $featured_comic = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
if ( $featured_comic->have_posts() ) : while ( $featured_comic->have_posts() ) :     
    $featured_comic->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content-homefeatured', get_post_format() );
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<div>
<h3>Subheading<h3>
<div><!—-for styling only-—>
</section>

<section>
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) );
if ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) :     
    $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="box<?php if($count%2 == 0 ) {echo '-1'; }; $count++; ?>">
    <?php get_template_part( 'content-homerecent', get_post_format() ); ?>
    </div><!—-for styling only-—>       
<?php endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</section>
```

content-page:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
<?php if ( ! is_page_template( 'page-templates/front-page.php' ) ) :
    the_post_thumbnail();
endif; ?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</header>

<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content();
wp_link_pages( array( 
    'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 
    'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<footer class="entry-meta">
<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->
```

content-homefeatured:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php if ( is_sticky() ) : ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="12345"]'); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
    <h1 class="entry-title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; // is_sticky() ?>
</article><!-- #post -->
```

content-homerecent:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
<div class="rcrop">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
<?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb'); ?>
</a>
</div>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
<h3 class="entry-title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h3>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="12345"]'); ?>
</article><!-- #post -->
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the contents of `content-homefeatured.php` (or possibly `content-homefeatured-post.php`).

Comment: I just updated the above code to add in the contents of each of the content-xx.php (minus the opening <?php...template info...?>)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the answer I received via Twitter here for others to see:

It was the sticky post under the Featured Comic section that was creating that phantom Untitled Article. So, by adding:

```
'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
```

to the arguments, it got rid of it. New code for the Featured Comic now looks like this:

```
<?php 
$featured_comic_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'tag' => 'buy-me, buyme',
); 

$featured_comic = new WP_Query( $featured_comic_args ); ?>
    <?php if ( $featured_comic->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $featured_comic->have_posts() ) : $featured_comic->the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content-homefeatured' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that helps someone else!